# How to use GPO or inTune to add script to Page Manipulator or TamperMonkey

Tags: google-chrome-extension, userscripts, gpo, intune, microsoft-edge-extension

We are running Enterprise software for which we need small UI tweaks (which the vendor is unwilling to support).
We are looking to implement user scripting via a browser extension. The 2 extensions we are considering are [Page Manipulator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/page-manipulator/mdhellggnoabbnnchkeniomkpghbekko?hl=en) and [TamperMonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en).
We've made a simple POC using Page Manipulator and only require 1 script in the browser as the script will read the necessary script/css/config from file.

Our infrastructure team is using GPO and inTune to push applications and settings to users.
They can push the selected extension to the users' browser.

What we are looking for is how we can push a script to the users browser (extension) using GPO, inTune or something alike?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can only push "raw" extensions with no user script installed via GPO or Intune. Also, pushing a script to any extension seems impossible. However, you can let users sync scripts themselves.

Take **Tampermonkey** as an example:

1. In Tampermonkey settings, switch `Config mode` to `Beginner` or `Advanced`, and then you'll have the `Userscript Sync` option.
2. Tick `Enable Userscript Sync`. And you may choose any of these sources to sync scripts. Then, select `save`. You'll be notified of the folder for script syncing. All you have to do is save your scripts in the relevant folder. You may use a public account for users to sync scripts.
3. (Optional) If sync fails, you can restart Tampermonkey in the settings.